# Converting "3H 30m" into 3.5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a SQL report for someone in which exists a column called Labour Hours of Engineer. In the column, the answers are shown as "3H 30M".

I want to change it to decimal. For example, "3H 30M" becomes 3.5.
Or another example is if an engineer works for 23 minutes, in the column, the answer should be 0.38 (rounded to 2 decimal places). 0.38 is the answer when you divide 23 mins by 60.

My current Formula is:

```sql
CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), CAST(Labour AS INT)%(24*60)/60) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),  CAST(Labour AS INT)%60)
```

Any way to achieve this, please share.

Comment: what does your current formula return? not your desired result?

Comment: Do you have any validation to ensure that you don't have values like `'5H 72M'`? Honestly, fixing your design would be the better choice here, rather than trying to consume the denormalised data.

Comment: @learning right now it returns 3.30 as the result. Require it to return as 3.5.

Comment: @Larnu yes it has validation and a couple of filters on it.

Comment: You already have the answer how to convert 30 mins to 0.5 hours as you said : `0.38 is the answer when you divide 23 mins by 60`. So what is your problem actually ?

Comment: Will the `H` and `M` *always* be there? If there the time is less than 1 hour, will it only be `'25M'` for example? If it's exactly a multiple of hours, will it only be `'5H'`?

Comment: @Squirrel current formula is not giving me the right answer and when I change it to (/60) it gives an integer value which is wrong. For example, if the value is 3H 24M, it gives 3.24 with (%60) formula and 3.3 with (/60) formula

Comment: @Larnu "H" and "M" wont be there at all. Currently, the report shows the data as "H" and "M" format. My client's request is to change it to decimal form as explained above

Comment: *""H" and "M" wont be there at all."* then what is your sample value `3H 30M`? That has *both* `'H'` and `'M'`. If they won't be there, why are they in your sample?

Comment: @Larnu I wrote 3H 30M as an example to explain you guys what I am trying to achieve. I have a big data set where I need a good formula which can convert data into the decimal format which is required.

Comment: So, again, "Will the `H` and `M` _always_ be there?"

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that the `'H'` and `'M'` are *always* there, one method would be some use of `CHARINDEX` to find the `'H'` and return the "first" characters and also strip those first characters. For minutes, you can just use simple division to get the decimal value

```sql
DECLARE @Time varchar(7) = '3H 30M';

SELECT @Time,
       CONVERT(int,LEFT(@Time,CHARINDEX('H',@Time)-1)) + (CONVERT(decimal(2,0),REPLACE(STUFF(@Time,1,CHARINDEX('H',@Time),''),'M',''))/60);
```

Comment: we do not need H and M. we have to remove it.

Comment: So why is `3.50000` wrong, @AK007 ? It has neither a `'H'` nor an `'M'` and matches the expected results in your question.

Comment: Yes 3.50 will be correct answer. I require it to 2 decimal places. We need to remove H and M. Right now data shows answer with H and M. Client wants it in decimal format

Comment: *"Right now data shows answer with H and M."* No it doesn't. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5cb72546b35c83465eeddccb1cb88ceb) The expression clearly brings back a decimal value, *not* a `'H'`, `'M'` value. Did you actually run the SQL provided..?

Answer (score 0):

This code will cover Hour minute or only minute

```
select Convert(decimal(26,2),
IIF(Labour like '%H%',(Convert(int, substring(Labour,0,(CHARINDEX('H',Labour)))) * 60 )+IIF(Labour like '%M%',Convert(int, substring(Labour,CHARINDEX('H',Labour)+1,CHARINDEX('M',Labour)-CHARINDEX('H',Labour)-1)),0)
,IIF(Labour like '%M%',Convert(int, substring(Labour,0,CHARINDEX('M',Labour))),0)) /60.00)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without using "Declare" as data is already there. we just need to convert it

Comment: Yes you could just put that in your select I will change that with your field name(Labour) right now

Comment: i get this error
Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: What is your field name exactly? and what is the type of that field?

Comment: because this error related to using substring for the non-string field, and in this query, I just used substring for your main field (Labour) and that should be varchar() to could contain '3H 30M' data